# Fortran find string in txt file

Tags: io, fortran

I would like to know how to find a string in a txt file and read the numbers after it.
The txt portion of the file is like:

```
...
x0 1 0 1 0.5 0
dx0 0 0 1 0 0
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
character :: c
real :: v1(1:5), v2(1:5)
integer :: i
...
open(10, file="input.txt", action="read")
...
read(unit = 10, fmt=*) c
do while(c/='x')
   read(unit = 10, fmt=*) c
end do
read(unit = 10, fmt=*) c
read(unit = 10, fmt=*) v1(1), v1(2), v1(3), v1(4), v1(5)
read(unit = 10, fmt=*) c c
read(unit = 10, fmt=*) v2(1), v2(2), v2(3), v2(4), v2(5)
close(10)
```

Is there any function that returns the position the do-while loop finds? What is a better way to find this position?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am new to fortran, I don't know how to find a string in a txt file.

Comment: Well write the code you do know how to write and clearly indicate the (hopefully) small areas of remaining difficulty.  SO isn't really the kind of place to get instruction in the basics of programming in Fortran (or any other programming language for that matter) and few of us are willing to write all your code for you.

Comment: Look into the 'index' function

Comment: I added my code. I looked for the index function, but it looks for a substring in a string. However, I have to look for it in a txt file. One way to do it is to add all my txt file to a string, but that does not seem reasonable. Or can I use the index function to find a string inside the txt?

Comment: You can read the lines of your file in sequence (in a loop) and search for it in a given line using `index`.

Comment: But the lines don't have all the same length, mostly on the beggining of the txt file. Should I just declare a 

`character*100 :: line`

and `read(10,*) line` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program below shows how to read numbers from a line where the search string is the first word. It uses an internal read, which is often useful in Fortran I/O.

```
program xinternal_read
implicit none
integer :: ierr
integer, parameter :: iu = 20
character (len=*), parameter :: search_str = "dx0"
real :: xx(5)
character (len=1000) :: text
character (len=10) :: word
open (unit=iu,file="foo.txt",action="read")
do
   read (iu,"(a)",iostat=ierr) text ! read line into character variable
   if (ierr /= 0) exit
   read (text,*) word ! read first word of line
   if (word == search_str) then ! found search string at beginning of line
      read (text,*) word,xx
      print*,"xx =",xx
   end if
end do
end program xinternal_read
```

The output is

```
xx = 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
```